# AVI Codec - No Joy with WMP in Windows 10 - Ideas?

Tags: video, codec, avi, wmp

I have several video series that I purchased a few years ago which are in the AVI format.  The vendor instructions included a requirement to download a TSCC codec.  A little digging revealed that the TSCC codec was from a company called TechSmith.  I grabbed and installed the codec and the vids played just fine on Windows 7 in Media Player.

Fast forward to 2015 and my machine is now running on Windows 10.  The AVIs won't play through the Win10 WMP, even after reinstalling the latest TSCC codec.  The original vendor won't answer my emails (LearnItFirst - beware) so I'm on my own.  Has anyone overcome this with Win10 WMP and TSCC-encoded AVI video?  If so, how did you solve it?

I'm not all that clear on the whole encoding concept - I assume that TechSmith offers some distinct encoding flavor, for which their codec is then needed to decode and view videos made with their encoding.  Is that right?  Does anyone have any other suggestions for how one can successfully view such videos on a Win10 box?  A different player, perhaps?  If a different player, how can one be sure that the TSCC encoding will be handled successfully by that player?

Thanks for any advice/feedback.

-- Rick

Comment: I guess it's DirectShow not supported by WMP. Try Graphedit to see if it plays at all, then install a proper (for the task) player. Edit: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407274(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Found a solution (from TechSmith):  The VLC media player. Open source. Well-recommended. Clean and comfortable UI.  Mission accomplished.